# I want to know editor Name or Modified Name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I want to know editor or modified person name in Sheets.

like... A2 cell is empty or some data, if any one Modified A2 cell i want to know modified user name in orther column like B2 or C2 column....

I want editor name who is edit the cell A2, Editor name should reflecte in orther cell ( B2,C2 )

Answer (score 0):

You could use `onEdit(e)` to check if the edit is done in a particular range, such as a column or row, and then log the change to another sheet along with the date. Somewhere in Stackoverflow you should find someone already having done this, but to get you started, here is the [reference to the trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) and a simple starter:

```js
 function onEdit(e){

  // Assuming you only want to track changes in column A
  const targetCol = 1 

  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();

  // Return if not the right column
  if(col != targetCol) return
  
  // log the change, along with the date and user to Sheet
  const oldValue = e.oldValue
  const newValue = e.value
  const today = new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10)
  const user = e.user.getEmail()

  // Assuming you do not want to track if no change occured
  if( oldValue == newValue ) return

  // Log the entry to Sheets
  const logEntry = [today, username, oldValue, newValue]
  const targetSheetName = "Changes"
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(targetSheetName).appendRow(logEntry)

 }
```

Comment: Thanks For the Help,

but the error i con't understood, can you please help on this....

12:55:09 PM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeType' of undefined
onEdit @ Code.gs:3

Comment: Sorry, my error. The property `changeType` is for the function `onEdit(event)` and therefore must be manually installed. I removed it from the code then it works.

Comment: error :- TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined

Comment: You should make edits in your sheet, then this function automatically runs whenever you edit a cell. You cannot run it per Apps Script.

Comment: example file name is ' Ruff ' and sheet name is sheet1, sheet2.sheet3

can i get same result in three sheets.

Particularly ( who is edit the cell from ' I2 to entire I column ' , Editor name should reflecte in orther cell column ' P2 to entire P column '

Comment: Please help on this

Comment: How can I edit and where to edit

Comment: Create a Sheet "Changes". Then Edit the cell in another Sheet, for example enter "Dog" in A2, hit Enter. And then enter "Cat" in A2.

Comment: i'm changed as per your instrutions, but out put is not showing

Comment: can you give your mail, I'll send detailed to you